# Oracle joining tables using WITH clause with SPLIT

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this table that is not linked to another table, because they don't have any same column. Now they want a report that will link both tables.

But the problem is the only common column to them is the WAFER_INFO column which has multiple values separated by a comma that is why I need to split them to make multiple records but different WAFER_INFO.

First Table

```
select wafer_info 
from bondertab_g3  
where tha_reel_id='TGDT349028H' 
order by insert_dm,tha_reel_id,processlk_ky
```

Results for the query above

```
TGK343067-22,TGK343067-25,TGK343067-24,TGK343067-23
```

Second Table

```
select hp_part_nr,wafer_id,good_cnt,total_rej_cnt,processlk_ky,toollk_ky,toolnrlk_ky,materiallk_ky 
from sawinsptab 
where wafer_id ='TGK343067-22';

select hp_part_nr,wafer_id,good_cnt,total_rej_cnt,processlk_ky,toollk_ky,toolnrlk_ky,materiallk_ky 
from sawinsptab 
where wafer_id ='TGK343067-25';

select hp_part_nr,wafer_id,good_cnt,total_rej_cnt,processlk_ky,toollk_ky,toolnrlk_ky,materiallk_ky 
from sawinsptab 
where wafer_id ='TGK343067-24';

select hp_part_nr,wafer_id,good_cnt,total_rej_cnt,processlk_ky,toollk_ky,toolnrlk_ky,materiallk_ky 
from sawinsptab 
where wafer_id ='TGK343067-23';
```

Basically just all of them in the first table

I already achieve on how to split all those records using this code

```
With DATA AS (
  select tha_reel_id, wafer_info str 
  from bondertab_g3
  where tha_reel_id='TGDT349028H'
)
SELECT A.tha_reel_id, trim(regexp_substr(A.str, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL)) WAFERID FROM DATA A
CONNECT BY instr(str, ',', 1, LEVEL - 1) > 0
```

Now my question is how can I connect my above query and connect it to the Second Table when the only column same is the WAFERID

Comment: If you need to split strings before joining you have a design bug and have to normalize your data. The server can't use any indexes on those columns and has to scan the entire table to find matches. This can get *very* slow for even a tiny amount of data

Comment: Share the table structure with sample I/O data thatll help

Comment: Your split function will generate duplicate rows that will increase in frequency exponentially as the number of input rows and number of delimited items increases (as the hierarchical query cannot correlate to a specific parent row so will correlate to all parent rows).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find where the `sawinsptab.wafer_id` (wrapped in your comma delimiters) is a sub-string of `bondertab_g3.wafer_info` (wrapped in your comma delimiters):

```sql
select hp_part_nr,
       wafer_id,
       good_cnt,
       total_rej_cnt,
       processlk_ky,
       toollk_ky,
       toolnrlk_ky,
       materiallk_ky 
from   sawinsptab s
where  EXISTS (
  select 1
  from   bondertab_g3 b
  where  b.tha_reel_id='TGDT349028H'
  and    ','||b.wafer_info||',' LIKE '%,'||s.wafer_id||',%'
);
```

or

```sql
select s.hp_part_nr,
       s.wafer_id,
       s.good_cnt,
       s.total_rej_cnt,
       s.processlk_ky,
       s.toollk_ky,
       s.toolnrlk_ky,
       s.materiallk_ky,
       b.other_column
from   sawinsptab s
       INNER JOIN bondertab_g3 b
       ON ( ','||b.wafer_info||',' LIKE '%,'||s.wafer_id||',%' )
where  b.tha_reel_id='TGDT349028H';
```

or, if you need to use an index on `wafer_id` and want to split the delimited string then, you can do it with a recursive sub-query factoring clause and simple string functions (rather than slow regular expressions):

```sql
select hp_part_nr,
       wafer_id,
       good_cnt,
       total_rej_cnt,
       processlk_ky,
       toollk_ky,
       toolnrlk_ky,
       materiallk_ky 
from   sawinsptab s
where  wafer_id IN (
  WITH delimiter_bounds ( wafer_info, startidx, endidx ) AS (
    SELECT wafer_info,
           1,
           INSTR( wafer_info, ',', 1 )
    FROM   bondertab_g3
    WHERE  tha_reel_id='TGDT349028H'
  UNION ALL
    SELECT wafer_info,
           endidx + 1,
           INSTR( wafer_info, ',', endidx + 1 )
    FROM   delimiter_bounds
    WHERE  endidx > 0
  )
  SELECT CASE
         WHEN endidx = 0
         THEN SUBSTR( wafer_info, startidx )
         ELSE SUBSTR( wafer_info, startidx, endidx - startidx )
         END
  from   delimiter_bounds
);
```

or

```sql
WITH delimiter_bounds ( wafer_info, other_column, startidx, endidx ) AS (
  SELECT wafer_info,
         other_column,
         1,
         INSTR( wafer_info, ',', 1 )
  FROM   bondertab_g3
  WHERE  tha_reel_id='TGDT349028H'
UNION ALL
  SELECT wafer_info,
         other_column,
         endidx + 1,
         INSTR( wafer_info, ',', endidx + 1 )
  FROM   delimiter_bounds
  WHERE  endidx > 0
)
select s.hp_part_nr,
       s.wafer_id,
       s.good_cnt,
       s.total_rej_cnt,
       s.processlk_ky,
       s.toollk_ky,
       s.toolnrlk_ky,
       s.materiallk_ky,
       b.other_column
from   sawinsptab s
       INNER JOIN (
         SELECT CASE
                WHEN endidx = 0
                THEN SUBSTR( wafer_info, startidx )
                ELSE SUBSTR( wafer_info, startidx, endidx - startidx )
                END AS wafer_id,
                other_column
         FROM   delimiter_bounds
       ) b
       ON ( s.wafer_id = b.wafer_id )
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but what if I also need the data on the second table bondertab_g3 included in the select. I've tried adding it but it doesn't coming up.

Comment: @Gene Updated with `INNER JOIN`

Answer (score 0):

You can change the first query to a CTE and then use that directly in your query:

```
with data as (
      select tha_reel_id, wafer_info str 
      from bondertab_g3
      where tha_reel_id = 'TGDT349028H'
     ),
     wafers as (
      select d.tha_reel_id, trim(regexp_substr(d.str, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL)) as waferid 
      from data d
      connect by instr(str, ',', 1, LEVEL - 1) > 0
     )
select s.*
from sawinsptab s 
where wafer_id in (select w.waferid from wafers);
```